# SharePoint - change the language of the site based on the browser language settings

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have a multi-lingual site collection and I would like the site to load on the language specified in the browser settings of the user. 
What is the best way to accomplish this?

Please provide some examples.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

In SharePoint 2010, use the [Multilingual user interface](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff805062.aspx):

> SharePoint Server 2010 selects the language in which to display pages of a site collection by using the first rule that applies from the following list:
>
> 1. Does the user have a preferred language for this site collection on this computer? If so, use the user's preferred language.
> 2. Is the language preference that is specified in the Web browser one of the supported languages for the page? If so, **use the preferred language of the browser**.
> 3. Otherwise, use the default, primary language for the site collection.

(note: emphasis mine)

For an example of how to configure the multilingual user interface, see [Use sites in multiple languages in SharePoint 2010](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/blogs/GetThePoint/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=366).

Comment: For your information, I am not using Variations. I simply have a MUI and I am using Pointfire and resources for localization. My question is, how can I load the site in the correct language without the user clicking or doing anything?

Comment: @IH-77 - and that is the answer I gave (notice the part highlighted in bold).